# Access the content of page if session is activated else activate session first

Tags: php, html, session

please help me solve this problem. I want to access content of a page only when Session is activated, else redirect user to activate session first. But when I redirect user to session page, it is stuck and cannot go back to content page. I am new here so please help me out from this problem.

```html
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  echo "cookie is not activated" ;
  header('Location: http://localhost/CC/Loginsession.php');
  die;
}
else {
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update in PHP</title>

</head>
<body>


<?php
  $servername="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $conn=mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
  
 if(!$conn ) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

  $sq1 = 'select * from biodata';
  mysql_select_db('firstdb');
  $display=mysql_query($sq1,$conn);

 if(!$display ) {
 
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    exit;
 }

 if (mysql_num_rows($display) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
 }
?>
 

<table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Fname</th>
          <th>Lname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Message</th>
    <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $display ) ){
            echo
            "<form method= 'post' />
    <tr>
       <td ><input name='UID' value='{$row['ID']}' readonly/></td>
       <td ><input name='upfname' value='{$row['fname']}' /></td>
       <td ><input name='uplname' value='{$row['lname']}' /></td>
       <td ><input name='upemail' value='{$row['email']}' /></td>
       <td ><input name='upphone' value='{$row['phone']}' /></td>
       <td ><input name='upmessage' value='{$row['message']}' /></td> 
       <td><input type='Submit' name='update' value='Update' id='".$row["ID"]."' </td> 
     </tr>
    </form>";
          }
?>
      </tbody>
</table>
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
  {
   
   $id   = $_REQUEST['UID'];
    $upfn = $_REQUEST['upfname'];
   $upln = $_REQUEST['uplname'];
      $upem = $_REQUEST['upemail'];
   $upph = $_REQUEST['upphone'];
   $upms = $_REQUEST['upmessage'];
   
   $up="UPDATE biodata 
   SET
   fname='$upfn',
   lname='$upln',
   email='$upem',
   phone='$upph',
   message='$upms' 
   WHERE ID = $id";
   $updbb=mysql_query($up,$conn);
   
   if($updbb){
  header('Location: http://localhost/Prac/updateinsamepage.php');
}

   
  }
}
?>
   
</body>
</html>>
```

and My session Login form code is here

```html
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 echo "Already registered as $_SESSION[username]" ;
}
 
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 
 $uname=htmlentities($_POST['username']);
 $pass=htmlentities($_POST['password']);
 
  if(!empty($uname) && !empty($pass)) {
    $_SESSION['username']=$uname;
    echo "Thanks<br />" . "UserName: $uname " . "Password: $pass";
    
   
    }
   
   else{
      echo "Please fill out the both fields";
   }
}
else {
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Loginsession</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
Username:<input type="text" id="username" name="username" /> <br /><br />
Password:<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/><br /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenvalue" value="<?php http://localhost/CC/Loginsession.php?username=overwritten ?>"/>
<input type="Submit" value="Login" name="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<?php }?>
<?php
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your PHP logs.  Your session login page has at least one glaring syntax error.  You have a random URL typed into server-side code, inside that `input` element.

Comment: @David (program):5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of nullprotectStyleSheet @ include.preload.js:393
Sir what does it mean?

Comment: You cannot use `header` if you've already sent content (via e.g. `echo`)

Comment: @apokrypos Bro thats redirect me correctly problem is somewhere else

Comment: It is because probably you have sent output before php `header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this script in place of header

```
echo '<script>window.location="localhost/CC/Loginsession.php"</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks bro solved Can you suggest me any good tutorial or book

Comment: I am also learning. I basically learn from youtube or udemy tutorials

Comment: Yes  bro I am asking questions here it help me alot